# Why the long frame in Chrome's Performance Monitor

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, monitor

I'm trying to understand why there's a long green frame of 872.9ms when it appears that not much is going on. All the little tasks are around 4ms. I'm expecting to see each of those wrapped in their own frame. That last task is big, and that's what I'm working on.

I enabled the FPS meter to make sure that it's not a Performance Monitor bug. FPS drop to 1, so I think the Perf Mon is working correctly.

[image: Performance Monitor screenshot]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I'm not sure your post fits [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, and I would suggest for it to be moved over [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I feel that this is on topic as it's a question regarding "_software tools commonly used by programmers_". Understanding how to use your tools definitely sounds topical to me.